# How to write a html file which can send a xml file to HTTP sever which run in Android device?

Tags: android, html

How to write a html file which can send a xml file to sever?
There is a requirement: send the below information to my HTTP sever which run in Android device.
1)The information is a xml format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<APMode>
<SSID>htc</SSID>
<password>1234567890</password>
<credentials>abcd</credentials>
</APMode >
```

2)The HTTP sever parse the HTTP body with `org.apache.http` APIs

```
 if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
                HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request)
                            .getEntity();
    parserXML(entity);

....
private void parserXML(HttpEntity entity) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = entity.getContent();
            printEntity(is);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        try {
            parser.setInput(is, "UTF-8");
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    String name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(SSID_TAG)) {
                        ssid = parser.nextText().trim();
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PASSWORD)) {
                        password = parser.nextText().trim();
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(CREDENTIAL)) {
                        credential = parser.nextText().trim();
                    } else if (name
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(DazzleApplication.DATETIME_TAG)) {
                        dateTime = parser.nextText().trim();
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But I don't know how to write the html which can load in browser?I can't modify the sever code now?

Comment: Do you want to parse the XML-document (sent from server) on your device? Or do you want to send the XML-document from your device to the server?

Comment: @Araw Thank you for reply! I need to send the information which is the xml format by browser. So I need to write a html file. But I don't know how to implement it. If I use `<form action=’http://localhost:1888’ method=post
enctype=’multipart/form-data’>
<input type=file name=’myfile’>
<input type=submit value=’Upload’>
</form>', I just get the file name using the `request.getEntity();'.

Comment: The name attribute is just a name you pass to the server.  I don't think you can set the actual file name programmatically. That's restricted for security reasons, to prevent malicious sites from stealing local files. It would be helpful to think why you need that unusual design in the first place: take a local file from the device and upload it to a server on the same device? Where does that file come from, with device-specific information? And so on. As the goal is 100% clear, there'll be an elegant design for it.